# alignment and 'right-pull'

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Somehow the button on the right is not centered (vertically) anymore when `pull-right` is used. 
How can it be placed in the middle?

```
       <li >
            <a  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm ">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ></span>
            </a>

            <a  type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ></span>
           </a>
       </li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1mawa84n/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `line-height` give padding to `li`

Try this:

CSS:

```
 li {
    background: rgba(254, 255, 251, 0.91) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    /* line-height: 3;*/
    margin: 0 0 -1px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```